# Linux Posix Message Queue: Message Too Long

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue

What I am trying to do is that while child processes find primes on files, parent should write them onto another file. Child processes will send primes as messages of M numbers. However, I am unable to receive messages, I get `Message too long` error.

```
int main() {
    mqd_t mq;
    mq = mq_open(MQ_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL);
    if (mq == (mqd_t) - 1) {
        perror("Cannot create msg queue");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Start child processes
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("Fork failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            char fileName[26];
            sprintf(fileName, "inter_file_%d.txt", i);
            FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
            if (file == NULL) {
                perror("Intermediate file open failed on child process");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            int64_t number;
            int64_t message[M];

            int curr_msg_size = 0;
            while (fscanf(file, "%" PRId64, &number) == 1) {
                if (isPrime(number)) {
                    message[curr_msg_size] = number;

                    if (curr_msg_size == (M - 1)) { // Message if fulled
                        int res = mq_send(mq, (const char *) message, (curr_msg_size + 1) * sizeof(int64_t), 0);

                        if (res == -1) {
                            perror("mq_send failed on full message");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                        curr_msg_size = 0;
                    }
                    curr_msg_size += 1;
                }
            }

            if (curr_msg_size > 0) {
                int res = mq_send(mq, (const char *) message, curr_msg_size * sizeof(int64_t), 0);

                if (res == -1) {
                    perror("mq_send failed on partial message");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            fclose(file);
            remove(fileName); // Remove the intermediate file
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // Child process terminates
        }
    }

    // Wait for all child processes to terminate
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int status;
        wait(&status);
    }

    // Open the output file
    FILE *output_file = fopen(output_file_name, "w");
    if (output_file == NULL) {
        perror("Output file open failed on parent process");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Read from the message queue and write to the output file
    int64_t message[M];
    while (mq_receive(mq, (char *) message, M * sizeof(int64_t), NULL) != -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            if (message[i] != 0) {
                fprintf(output_file, "%" PRId64 "\n", message[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Close the output file
    if (fclose(output_file) != 0) {
        perror("Output file close failed on parent process");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Close and unlink the message queue
    mq_close(mq);
    mq_unlink(MQ_NAME);

    return 0;
}
```

I guess I am using the mq_receive method in a wrong way, I hope someone can see my mistake and tell me.

Comment: How do you know it is `mq_receive` that is failing with Message too long?  I don't see any `perror()` call or error handling with your receiver.  Please provide a [concise example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the output you see, and show us that output exactly (cut and paste) please.

Answer (score 2):

[The `mq_send` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html) will return an `EMSGSIZE` error if

> `msg_len` was ***greater*** than the `mq_msgsize` attribute of the message queue

[The `mq_receive` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html) will return an `EMSGSIZE` error if

> `msg_len` was ***less*** than the `mq_msgsize` attribute of the message queue

<sub>[Emphasis mine in both quotes]</sub>

The `mq_msgsize` attribute is set with [the `mq_open` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html), and according to [the message queue overview manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) the default is `8192` bytes.

Since you don't set the attribute, it will be the default value. So when you send, you have to keep the messages smaller than `8192` bytes. And when you receive, you need to have a buffer of at least `8192` bytes.

Since you don't provide us with a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we don't know what `M` is, or how many bytes you attempt to send or receive.

---

And the lesson for today: Always read the relevant manual pages.

Comment: So, I got your point and thank you. The thing I do not understand is that I can send the messages without any problem, but I can't receive them. They are the same object in that matter. And you may assume that M is 3 if you need to know.

Comment: @DenizTuna If `M == 3` then `sizeof message` should be equal to `sizeof int64_t * 3` which is `8 * 3` which is `24`. Much less than the default `8192` bytes needed to be able to receive the messages.