# Linux Posix Message Queue mq_receive Stucks/Not Returning

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue

My program successfully compiles into an executable as anticipated. Nevertheless, when I run the exact **same executable** with **identical parameters**, sometimes it works and returns, and other times it still works in some way but *never* returns.

After putting printf statements everywhere I found out which part of the program stuck and it is this part:

```
int64_t message[M];
for (;;) {
    // Check if there are no more messages to be received
    mq_getattr(mq, &mqAttrs);
    if (mqAttrs.mq_curmsgs <= 0 && (*childProcessCounterPtr) <= 0) {
        break;
    }

    char charMessage[M * sizeof(int64_t)];
    ssize_t received = mq_receive(mq, charMessage, maxMsgSize, NULL);

    if (received == -1) { // Error
        perror("mq_receive failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else { // Message received successfully
        int messageSize = (int) received / sizeof(int64_t);
        memcpy(message, charMessage, received);

        for (int i = 0; i < messageSize; i++) {
            fprintf(outputFile, "%" PRId64 "\n", ((int64_t *) message)[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When/if the program stuck, the code after mq_receive never executes so the overall program never returns. Even perror statement never executes. I tried to put a printf after mq_receive which was not executed either.

The thing I do not understand is why it works sometimes, because when it works it gives the expected output as well. Since it works occasionally, I am also failing to find an error or any other kind of bug.

In case you need, I am putting the mq_send and mq_open parts of my program:

**mq_open:**

```
mqd_t mq;
mq = mq_open(POSIX_MQ_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666, NULL);
if (mq == -1) {
    perror("mq_open failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Get the maximum message size
struct mq_attr mqAttrs;
mq_getattr(mq, &mqAttrs);
maxMsgSize = mqAttrs.mq_msgsize;
```

**mq_send:**

```
int currPrimeCountInMsg = 0;
int64_t candidateNumber, message[M];

while (fscanf(file, "%" PRId64, &candidateNumber) == 1) {
    if (isPrime(candidateNumber)) {
        message[currPrimeCountInMsg] = candidateNumber; // Add the prime to the message
        currPrimeCountInMsg++;

        if (currPrimeCountInMsg == M) { // If the message is fulled
            char charMessage[M * sizeof(int64_t)];
            memcpy(charMessage, message, M * sizeof(int64_t));

            if (mq_send(mq, charMessage, M * sizeof(int64_t), 0) == -1) { // Send the message
                perror("mq_send (on child) failed");
               _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            currPrimeCountInMsg = 0; // Reset the message
        }
    }
}
```

And, also yes, I am closing and unlinking the queue at the very end of the program:

```
mq_close(mq);
mq_unlink(POSIX_MQ_NAME);
```

Comment: After I put O_EXCL flag in mq_open, I have started to get EEXIST file exists error.

Comment: OK, apparently, first a few runs after reboot returns. Then, the program decides not to return.

Comment: You are ([again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77280071)) not showing us everything that's going on in the program.  Please cut this down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).